# debug optimized javascript with require.js r.js

Tags: requirejs

Without  `r.js` optimizing all workes great with my `require js` modules. 
But with optimized js files ...

```
r.js -o public/js/app.build.js
```

... where `app.build.js` is ...

```
({
    appDir: "../",
    baseUrl: "js",
    dir: "../../appdirectory-build",
    paths: {
        jquery: "./jquery-1.9.1",
        jade: "lib/requireJade"
    },
    modules: [
        {
            name: "main"
        }
    ]
})
```

... and output without errors and warnings ...

```
Optimizing (standard.keepLines) CSS file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css
Optimizing (standard.keepLines) CSS file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
Optimizing (standard.keepLines) CSS file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.css
Optimizing (standard.keepLines) CSS file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Optimizing (standard.keepLines) CSS file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/css/media.css
Optimizing (standard.keepLines) CSS file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/css/style.css
Optimizing (standard.keepLines) CSS file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/min/bundle/3c95026_global.css

Tracing dependencies for: main
Uglifying file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/js/bootstrap.js
Uglifying file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
Uglifying file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/js/app.build.js
Uglifying file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/js/jquery-1.9.1.js
Uglifying file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/js/lib/bootstrapRequire.js
Uglifying file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/js/lib/requireJade.js
Uglifying file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/js/main.js
Uglifying file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/js/main_built.js
Uglifying file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/js/require.js
Uglifying file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/js/submain/load_digits.js
Uglifying file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/js/submain/load_map.js
Uglifying file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/js/submain/load_more_records.js
Uglifying file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/js/submain/load_more_records_event.js
Uglifying file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/js/submain/submit_number_chooser_form.js
Uglifying file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/js/yamapsapi2.js
Uglifying file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/js/yandex-map-show-group.js
Uglifying file: /pathToProject/appdirectory-build/js/yandex-map.js

bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css
----------------
bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css

bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
----------------
bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css

bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.css
----------------
bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.css

bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
----------------
bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

css/media.css
----------------
css/media.css

css/style.css
----------------
css/style.css

min/bundle/3c95026_global.css
----------------
min/bundle/3c95026_global.css

js/main.js
----------------
js/jquery-1.9.1.js
js/yamapsapi2.js
js/yandex-map.js
js/submain/load_map.js
js/lib/requireJade.js
jade!lib/jade/records
js/submain/load_more_records.js
js/submain/load_more_records_event.js
js/submain/submit_number_chooser_form.js
js/main.js
```

### ... I **got errors** in chrome console when page loaded...

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
(anonymous function) main.js:172
anonymous main.js:172
e.ajax.success main.js:172
l main.js:172
c.fireWith main.js:172
N main.js:172
r
```

... some functions don't work on my page

So it's ok I got line number where error occurs: `172`. But the problem is that optimized `main.js` row number `172` got length `206490`. It's hard to find error such way.

## How to debug it and find place where error actually occurs?

Without any optimizing I don't have any error. With optimazing I got error and too poor output to debug this error.

I tried to use [excludeShallow](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#shallow) with suspected buggy file

```
r.js -o public/js/app.build.js excludeShallow=load_more_records
```

But error still occurs and output still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make main.js more debuggable I added `optimize: "none"` in config.

```
({
    appDir: "../",
    baseUrl: "js",
    dir: "../../appdirectory-build",
    paths: {
        jquery: "./jquery-1.9.1",
        jade: "lib/requireJade"
    },
    modules: [
        {
            name: "main"
        }
    ],
    optimize: "none"

})
```

This option restricts to write all `js` in one line. Then I saw the actual line where error occurs. And to fix error add ...

```
pragmasOnSave: {
      excludeJade : true
    }
```

... to `app.build.js` as written [here](https://github.com/deedubs/require-jade#optimizing).

And error was fixed. Final `app.build.js`:

```
({
    appDir: "../",
    baseUrl: "js",
    dir: "../../appdirectory-build",
    paths: {
        jquery: "./jquery-1.9.1",
        jade: "lib/requireJade"
    },
    modules: [
        {
            name: "main"
        }
    ],
    // optimize: "none",
    pragmasOnSave: {
      excludeJade : true
    }
})
```